# Keep review buttons in the same place even when the guidance is long

Tags: feature-request, review, design, vote-to-reopen

When review Reopen Votes, if the corresponding guidance text for the close reason is long, it squeezes the buttons into a vertical list:

[image]

While this does make robo-reviewing more difficult, I'd like such important buttons to remain in the same place, like this:

[image]

Comment: I assume not many reviews get done on that site. I would be very hesitant to click big red buttons, no matter where they are positioned ...